# Nemo/Nautilus - Where does the list of 'other applications' reside?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, thunar, nemo

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 with Nemo as my default file manager (because I like the split screen)

I was trying to change a default application to set Edrawmax to open .eddx files.
If I go to Nemo or Nautilus | Properties of the file | Open with and browse through the list of applications I see this:

[image]

Note the two entries for edrawmax. They were not there the first time I tried this, I had to type 'edrawmax' in the commandline box. It worked fine then but for some reason reverted back to archive manager being the default application (probably after a recent regular application upgrade). I went to rest Edrawmax as the default app for eddx files and selected one of these. When I double clicked on the file Edrawmax spat an error saying it could not open the file.
I tried the same thing using Thunar. It shows this:
[image]
Note the extra entry for Edrawmax with the applications actual icon beside it. But even selecting this I got the same error, that Edrawmax could not open the file.
I then (in Thunar) typed edrawmax in the commandline input and that worked, I can now double click on a .eddx file and it opens correctly in Edrawmax.

My questions are:
Where are these entries stored so I can remove those two entries for edrawmax in nemo?
and
Why did the program (with icon) not show in Nemo or Nautilus but did in Thunar?
and
When I set it to work I had to type the command in the box to get it to work rather than select the item in the list (even the one with the icon in Thunar)?

Comment: The easiest way is only for edrawmax 11.1.2(default application to set Edrawmax to open .eddx files.)!!! In the terminal sudo su. Then: cp /opt/EdrawMax-11/edrawmax.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/ then: update-desktop-database /usr/share/applications then: update-mime-database /usr/share/mime

Comment: After deleting the .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications and doing what you said here, Edrawmax is now the default application for eddx files. Thanks. This should have been written as the answer rather than a comment so I could give it the green tick!

Comment: Used these links: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom.html.en https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en  Files .vsdx ,.vsds will open in edrawmax if in the terminal gedit ~/.config/mimeapps.list Add to section [Added Associations] application/vnd.ms-visio.drawing.main+xml=edrawmax.desktop; and application/vnd.visio=edrawmax.desktop;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of applications shown in the "Open with" dialog is compiled from the `.desktop` files installed on your system, and which also populate the menu. These are located in `~/.local/share/applications` and in any `application` directory under one of the paths listed in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`. Only these launchers that are configured to handle a file or an URI are included in the "Open with" dialog, i.e., applications that have `%f`, `%F`, `%u` or `%U`  as one of their arguments on the `Exec=` line.

Comment: So I saw three entries in ~/.local/share/applications for edrawmax. No idea why but I deleted them. Now they do not appear in the list of other applications (good) and following Johan Palych advise in the comment to my original post I now have Edrawmax as the default. Oddly enough when I set eddx files to open with Edrawmax for some reason zip files also defaulted to this, I had to reset the default application for them back to Archive Manager. Ubuntu does some strange things at times. I'm ticking this as the solution but it was really a combination of your advice and Johans.